# Google speech-to-text api return "|" result using C#

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google Speech-To-Text to recognize via mic in Windows PC device.
My target language is "ja-JP" and I've already coded app that can recognize some japanese sentences. But I sometime got a strange result Like a "2010|ニセンジュー,ニーゼロイチゼロ 年代|ネンダイ".
I confused such result that included "|". Anybody knows how to create a correct result? Please help me.

I created my application, using Windows C# Google Nuget Library, "Google.Cloud.Speech.V1" version 1.2.0. Language is "ja-JP".

Here is my config information.

```
var recogConfig = new RecognitionConfig()
{
   Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
   SampleRateHertz = 16000,
   LanguageCode = "ja-JP",
   Model = "command_and_search",
   ProfanityFilter = false,
};

StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
{
   Config = recogConfig,
   InterimResults = true,
   SingleUtterance = true,
};
```

I expect the output of "transcript" is "2010年代の".
but the actual output is "2010|ニセンジュー,ニーゼロイチゼロ 年代|ネンダイ の|ノ".

StreamingRecognizeResponse result is below.
{[ { "alternatives": [ { "transcript": "2010|ニセンジュー,ニーゼロイチゼロ 年代|ネンダイ の|ノ" } ], "isFinal": true, "resultEndTime": "2.820s" } ]}

Comment: Seems you're getting [rubi text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_character) along with transcription. "ニセンジュー" and "ニーゼロイチゼロ" are possible pronunciations of "2010", "ネンダイ" is the pronunciation of "年代", and "ノ" is the pronunciation of "の". Dunno about the API itself, but it should be okay to just split the result by space, split each component by bar, then join the first part of each element.

Comment: Thx for replying Amadan!! Yea, I think that your opinion is correct. So I'm gonna change my code. But I want to find any formal spec in google document. So far, I could not find anything. If someone find "rubi text" spec, please let me know about it.